# PySpark org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found:

Tags: python, apache-spark, twitter, pyspark

I have an issue similar to many other posted questions regarding PySpark, but none of those solutions seem applicable to my problem, so I'm posting a new question.

I'm following this tutorial https://github.com/emiljdd/Tweepy-SparkTwitterI, but can't seem to get step 7 in Phase II to work.

Running this code:

```
count = 0
while count < 10:

 time.sleep( 3 )
 top_10_tweets = sqlContext.sql( 'Select tag, count from tweets' )
 top_10_df = top_10_tweets.toPandas() # Dataframe library
 display.clear_output(wait=True) #Clears the output, if a plot exists.
 sns.plt.figure( figsize = ( 10, 8 ) )
 sns.barplot( x="count", y="tag", data=top_10_df)
 sns.plt.show()
 count = count + 1
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: tweets; line 1 pos 23
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:617)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:640)...
```

I can of course post more code if it would help, but I really am just following the tutorial without any changes.

The streaming-setup from Phase I seems fine, as I can see the Tweets being sent.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I guess the dataframe doesn't created such as tempview. You must create dataframe with "tweets" temp view name. Sample code is:

```
dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("tweets")
```

Please check your code contains this creation.

Example snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Dataframe example').getOrCreate()

dataframe = spark.read.csv("/path/to/file.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True)
dataframe.show()
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("tempview")

spark.sql('select id,name from tempview').show()
spark.sql('select avg(age) from tempview').show()
```

Comment: Can you please add a snippet ?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I tried that but it did not work since my output was a DStream RDD but the normal RDD. Do you have any idea how we can create a tempview of Dtream RDD ?

Comment: You can use spark structered streaming. Please check that: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Answered question on the github issues page for this https://github.com/emiljdd/Tweepy-SparkTwitterI/issues/5

Problem is step 4 on that tutorial this line of code

```
( lines.flatMap( lambda text: text.split( " " ) ) 
             .filter( lambda word: word.lower().startswith("#") ) 
             .map( lambda word: ( word.lower(), 1 ) ) 
             .reduceByKey( lambda a, b: a + b ) 
             .map( lambda rec: Tweet( rec[0], rec[1] ) ) 
             ##.foreachRDD( lambda rdd: rdd.toDF().sort( desc("count") # the desc here doesnt work with 
             .foreachRDD( lambda rdd: rdd.toDF().sort("count")      
             .limit(10).registerTempTable("tweets") ) )
```

remove the desc in the sort and it should work. It doesnt throw an exception but it should

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be ->
1. your spark default is in yarn, change it local mode.

2.There is only one executor working, which is receiving message, but no executor is processing message.

Solution: 
while opening your jupyter follow the below command.(ensure your pyspark2 by default opens in jupyter)

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ **pyspark2 --master local[2]**

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be with the SPARK version not being compatible with your SQLContext code.

I have made some changes to the code and got it working.

Step1:
Import Spark Session from Sql functions

`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext`

Step2: 
Created a Spark Sql sessions:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Sparksql').getOrCreate()`

Step3:
Instead of registerTempTable use createOrReplaceTempView :
`.limit(10).createOrReplaceTempView("tweets")`

Step4:
Check if the Sql works as below:

```
top_10_tweets = spark.sql( 'Select tag, count from tweets' )
top_10_tweets.show()
```

Please let me us know how you get on with it.